# What limits performance of worker?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, redis, sidekiq, foreman

I use Sidekiq for job processing. Using Foreman, I set up six processes in my Procfile:

```
redirects: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
redirects2: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
redirects3: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
redirects4: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
redirects5: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
redirects6: bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q redirects
```

These processes performed at about 1600+ jobs (simple job to increment some hashes in Redis) per second with all 10 threads busy most of the time. I scaled my Digital Ocean droplet from 8 to 12-core, and performance fell to ~400 per second. For each process, there are only 3-5 busy threads out of 10.

What I did to try to fix the issue:

- Make `perform` method empty
- Use less/more process count
- Use less/more concurrency
- Split queue to server-specific queues (there are three express.js clients from another servers puts jobs in queues)
- Trying with different `hz` values in redis.conf
- Setting `somaxconn` to 1024 (`tcp-backlog` in redis.conf too)
- Turning off RDB save and use only AOF
- Flush all Redis dbs (there are two databases for all that logic: one for sidekiq and another for hashes in my workers)
- Running sidekiq from terminal without Foreman (to check if it is Foreman issue)

None of above helped me. What could have caused the performance loss?

Comment: This is a good candidate to create an [issue directly](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues) or even ask Mike Perham.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for advice. [Issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2576) created.

Comment: There's hundreds of variables that can cause issues and no way to tell which is at fault.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you find the solution?

Comment: nah, it's more likely amount of CPU performance depending on core number of droplet.